# Forward emails from specific domain in Exchange

Tags: exchange-2007, mail-forwarding

Our Exchange server handles emails for `@ourdomain.com` (for example).

We have multiple clients that will send emails to our `support@ourdomain.com` email address and we want to configure server-side rules that will forward emails from each client's domain to a different email address within our exchange server.

For example:

`steve@client01.com sends an email to support@ourdomain.com and we forward it to client01.support@ourdomain.com`

`phil@client02.com sends an email to support@ourdomain.com and we forward it to client02.support@ourdomain.com`

...and so on.

It would be nice if we can additionally stop the email arriving in the support@ourdomain.com mailbox, but that is not a specific requirement.

We have a rule setup in Outlook that sort of works, but it doesn't do all from a domain only specific email addresses. It does work when Outlook is not running which is a start.

I realise it would be easier to give each client a partiuclar email address and have them email straight to that rather than all use the same, but this is what I have been asked to setup.... :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think you can do this through transport rules.  On your Exchange Management Console, under Organization Configuration -> Hub Transport -> Transport Rules.  If you set the rule to something like,

When any of the recipients in the To field is support@ourdomain.com 
and When the from address contains client01, 
redirect to client01.support@ourdomain.com.

The redirect should mean it doesnt go into the mailbox as well

Comment: Just been looking at the exact same thing!

Comment: You might need to restart your microsoft exchange transport service on your hub transport server to get it to work.